# Get rid of NaN as key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, nan

I have a dictionary in which one key is a NaN, and I want to delete the key and its corresponding value. I have tried this:

```
from math import isnan

clean_dict = filter(lambda k: not isnan(k), dict_HMDB_ID)
```

but the clean_dict is not a dictionary. I want to output it from python, but I get ''

Answer (score 2):

`filter` doesn't return a dictionary. It returns a list in Python 2 and a filter object in Python 3.

You can use [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(d)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d.pop('b')
print(d)
# {'a': 1}
```

And in your specific case,

```
dict_HMDB_ID.pop(float('NaN'))
```

For the sake of completeness. it *could* be done with a dictionary comprehension but there is no point in iterating since keys are unique anyway

```
clean_dict = {k: v for k, v in dict_HMDB_ID.items() if not math.isnan(k)}
```

If you insist on using `filter` here (you really **shouldn't**) you will need to:

1. pass it `dict_HMDB_ID.items()` so it will keep the original values
2. provide a custom function because it will now operate on `(key, value)` tuples.
3. transform the returned filter object (it will contain an iterator with `(key, value)` tuples) back to a dictionary

```
import math

dict_HMDB_ID = {1: 'a', float('Nan'): 'b'}
clean_dict = dict(filter(lambda tup: not math.isnan(tup[0]), dict_HMDB_ID.items()))
print(clean_dict)
# {1: 'a'}
```

I should probably mention that the first approach (`.pop`) directly modifies the `dict_HMDB_ID` while the other two create a new dictionary. If you wish to use `.pop` *and* create a new dictionary (leaving `dict_HMDB_ID` as it is) you can create a new dictionary with `dict`:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
new_d = dict(d)
new_d.pop('b')
print(d)
# {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
print(new_d)
# {'a': 1}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could do:

```
from math import nan
dict_HMDB_ID.pop(nan)
clean_dict = dict_HMDB_ID
```

or the other way around if you wna to preserve `dict_HMDB_ID`

```
from math import nan
clean_dict = dict(dict_HMDB_ID)
clean_dict.pop(nan)
```

Comment: Edited answer to remove iteration